# Running 2 onclick functions in the same link

Tags: jquery, function

Here's my problem. I want to run a delete function on the click of a href link but I also want to have a confirmation popup. At the moment the delete script is running if I click OK OR Cancel, so obviously I only want it to run if I click OK. Here is the code:

```
<a class=\"deletelink delete$postid\" href=\"#\" data-post=\"$postid\" data-type=\"$posttype\" data-file=\"$postmedia\" onclick=\"return deletepost();\">Delete</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function deletepost(){
var deletequestion = confirm("You are about to delete one of your posts");
if(deletequestion){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.deletelink').on('click', function()
    {
    var post = $(this).attr("data-post");
    var file = $(this).attr("data-file");
    var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
    jQuery.post("php/delete.php", {
    post:post,
    file:file,
    type:type
    },  function(data, textStatus){
    if(data == 1){
    $('.delete' + post).html("Deleted").addClass("disableClick");
    }else{
    $('.delete' + post).html("Error");
    }
    });
    return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to club them together

```
<a class=\"deletelink delete$postid\" href=\"#\" data-post=\"$postid\" data-type=\"$posttype\" data-file=\"$postmedia\">Delete</a>
```

And

```
$('.deletelink').on('click', function() {
    var deletequestion = confirm("You are about to delete one of your posts");
    if(!deletequestion ){
        return;
    }
    var post = $(this).attr("data-post");
    var file = $(this).attr("data-file");
    var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
    jQuery.post("php/delete.php", {
        post:post,
        file:file,
        type:type
    },  function(data, textStatus){
        if(data == 1){
            $('.delete' + post).html("Deleted").addClass("disableClick");
        }else{
            $('.delete' + post).html("Error");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I can't believe the solution was so simple. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

'@Arun P Johny' is quite correct. I would also advice something like:

```
<a ... confirmation='deleteCheck' ../>
```

+

```
 function deleteCheck() {
       var deletequestion = confirm("You are about to delete one of your posts");
       // and so on ...
    }

$('.deletelink').on('click', function() {
    var link = $(this);
    var confirmation = link.attr('confirmation');
    if (confirmation != undefined && !window[confirmation]()) {
       return;
    }

    ... // continue
}
```